# How to add button or Link to visualforce page whose standard controller is not same as applying tab?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have visualforce page `CompetitorSearch.page` that use `CompSearchDummy__c` as standard controller.

```
<apex:page StandardController="CompSearchDummy__c" extensions="CompetitorSearch">
```

If I am to add custom button on the page of `CompSearchDummy`, `CompetitorSearch.page` shows up for the page destination.

But I have `Talent` page which use `Talent__c sObject` and when I tried to add custom button and attempt to set destination, `CompetitorSearch.page` does not show up as an option because I did not set `Talent__c` as `standard controller`.

Is it possible to somehow add my CompetitorSearch.page link to Talent page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add an `apex:commandButton` to go to another page. When you were on the same page, it was just refreshing itself, but to go to another page, you need to specify an action in the `apex:commandButton` that points to a method in a controller extension that returns a PageReference for where you want to go. Like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!gotoCompetitorSearch}" value="Competitor Search" />

public PageReference gotoCompetitorSearch() {
    return Page.CompetitorSearch;
}
```

Note, if you don't really need a button or special logic and just want to go to another page, you can do this with just an `apex:outputLink` with no need for a controller extension, like this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.CompetitorSearch}">CompetitorSearch</apex:outputLink>
```